# Crystal report for display records

Tags: crystal-reports

I ve many columns in my dataset to display in Crystal report ......
but i cant extend the page of crystal report....how can i?

is it possible to display records from dataset without design the crystal report desingning?

Comment: I think you should try refrasing that. Do you wish to extend the report horizontaly **(make the report wider)** ?

Comment: you mean the changing the page to landscape? check the printer options to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hai DX,

Have a look at this  [Crystal report from a dataset](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rsubhajit/CrystalReportwithDataSet03012006060655AM/CrystalReportwithDataSet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Page Setup -> Orientation and check landscape.

There's ways to display more columns on a report.  For example, making the font small, making the width of the columns smaller, changing the page layout to landscape, etc.

You can also adjust the margins in the report to be less if you really want (File -> Page Setup -> Margins).

The instructions above are from my Crystal 9 IDE, but they should be similar in updated versions.